# Create a database link from autonomous database using heterogeneous services

Tags: oracle

I want to create a database link from an autonomous database in the cloud to a MySQL database. Oracle CLoud Documentation only speaks about database links between two Oracle Databases:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/database-links.html#GUID-84FB6B85-D60D-4EDC-BB3C-6485B2E5DF4D

I've created database links between Oracle and other databases in the past, but always in on-premise installations. Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not possible to do directly. What you can do is to make it a 2-hops dblink: from ADB to an Oracle db on prem, and from there to the mysql one. Awkward and not ideal at all, but may work.

Comment: Try asking this question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). This is not a good place to ask database infrastructure questions.

Comment: Good idea @gsalem, that should work.

Comment: Thanks @APC, i'm going to keep that in mind for future questions/replies.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install only oracle server software on the host where mysql is running.
2. Configure the oracle listener on this host.
3. Configure a heterogeneous connection (HSODBC) to this listener.
4. Create dblink between the cloud and this host.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Demin, I'll give it a try! It should work.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_CLOUD_ADMIN.CREATE_DATABASE_LINK has a parameter named gateway_link. You will need to pass that as true in order to create a database link from Autonomous Database to your gateway.

See details here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/database-links-other-databases.html#GUID-E4F35EEE-3147-4822-A9EB-A341D87E4ECF